# how to detect if inside a matched pair?

Tags: elisp, syntax

**Q:** is there a general way to detect whether or not point is inside a matched pair of characters?

That is: is there a general predicate function (or something) that can determine if point is in-between a matched pair or some arbitrarily-chosen characters?  I'm thinking about one that would evaluate to `t` in, say, the following scenarios, with `!` referring to point:

```
"!"   (quotes in general)
``!'' (LaTeX quotes)
$!$   (LaTeX math)
(!)   (lisp parens)
*!*   (org emphasis)
```

*Edit*: `syntax-ppss` seems to be a good starting point, but it's not clear to me how one would adapt it to multi-character matched pairs (eg, the ``LaTeX quotes'', or even matched `<b>html tags</b>`).  I'm wondering if there's a general solution, or if it would require a purpose-built parser.

Answer (score 16):

`syntax-ppss` might be of help here.  It [returns a list](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Low_002dLevel-Parsing.html) that also has these elements:

- element 0: depth in parens
- element 3: non-nil if inside a string

You could use it like this:

```
(or (> (nth 0 (syntax-ppss)) 0)
    (nth 3 (syntax-ppss)))
```

With a properly set up syntax-table in the buffer (for strings and matching parens) the function should do what you expect.  If using the mode's syntax-table is not possible than you could resort to using `with-syntax-table`.

Comment: I should point out that the docstring of `parse-partial-sexp` explains the data structure returned by `syntax-ppss` in more detail than the Elisp manual section I linked to.

Answer (score 2):

If you want for example to check if between curly braces, use this:

```
(and (looking-back "{") (looking-at "}"))
```

Sure, you can replace the curly braces by whatever you want.

**EDIT:**

A more useful function will be something close to this:

```
(defun test-inside-curly-braces ()
 (interactive)
 (when (and (looking-back "{\\(.*?\\)") (looking-at "\\(.*?\\)}"))
  (message "inside curly braces")))
```

Comment: That only works if point is on the closing `}`, and there's nothing between the `{}`. Getting paired delimiters right with regexps can be tricky. Better to use `syntax-pps` as @paprika suggested.

Comment: @Tyler works only if point on closing `}` is not the behaviour I've seen :\ but yeah, get the pairs using regexps is tricky, indeed

Comment: `looking-at` examines the text starting at point. unless point is on the `}` your first statement above shouldn't work? Maybe a difference between Emacs versions. :/